# How to attach latitude and longitude values to pixels values in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, geotiff-tiff, landsat, landsat-8

I am trying to create space time cubes of LANDSAT 8 images in ArcGIS. The space time cubes can be created using only feature classes, so I need to convert from TIFF to pixel values with Dates and Latitude, Longitudes attached.The TIFF files obtained from USGS show only values and counts in attribute table. The properties of TIFF file show a spatial reference but I can't find a way to add it to attributes table.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided (and your actual needs), there are at least two options. 1) Vector-based. Convert the polygons in your data layer to points, then create new fields corresponding to latitude and longitude respectively. Then use Calculate Geometry to fill in these two fields with the latitude and longitude values of each point. 2) Raster-based. You can create two rasters, one containing only latitude values and the other containing only longitude values. Then overlay these two rasters with the data you have. By doing so, every pixel in your data cube are tied with a latitude and a longtitude value.

In either case, you'll probably need to convert the projection first since Landsat data by default are in UTM projection.